# Search Verticals defined in Microsoft 365 Administration Portal not showing up in SharePoint Online sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-search

Yesterday, I created a **Search Vertical and Result Type** in the Microsoft 365 admin portal. It is a custom connector to get external data in SharePoint Search build using Graph API. It is more than 24 hours and still the vertical is not showing up when I am searching in SharePoint Search Textbox in Modern sites. **When I am using graph search API then it is able to get the result**.

**Custom Connector Status**
[image]

**Search ResultType:**
[image]

**Custom Vertical:**
[image]

Can someone help to point me to correct direction as to why I am not able to see verticals in SharePoint online while searching.

Answer (score 0):

Check to verify your verticals appear in office.com and bing.com (if Bing search is enabled in your tenant).

If they do, when you search on an SPO site, if the path shows "Organization > <SiteTitle>", then click on the "Organization" link. You should then see your organization-wide verticals you created in the Microsoft Search admin center.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't change anything and today I am able to see it properly in Bing as well as in SharePoint search. It took for my tenant approx. 30-36 hours (dev tenant).